# How to know when a image is downloaded from my server

Tags: php, file, date, logging, time

I have a problem, I need to know if exists any method to register (in a txt file) the date and time when a image is downloaded, for example, I have www.myserver.com/image421.jpg, an user enter the link, right click the image and save in his computer, how can I register that? Only Date and time, I know how to manage txt with php, I only need the method for save that information, it's possible? Thank you so much! (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: do you also want to count when the browser shows the image?

Comment: I already have it, but thanks :)

Comment: You can scan your server's access log to find all the downloads of the file.

Comment: Redirect the image URL to a script that updates a database and sends the file contents.

Comment: have what? not sure what you are asking anymore?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I get the information from access.log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specifically capture a user's click on "Save image as" on the browser's context menu, there is no JS event for that.

But a workaround may be disabling the context menu and force the user to download the picture by clicking on a link. When the link is clicked, you do whatever you want; make an AJAX call to a PHP file etc:

[JSFIDDLE 1](https://jsfiddle.net/erdemolcay/afgcayyh/)

```
$('img').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    return false;
});

$(function () {
    $('#download-btn').click(function () {
        // Do whatever you want...
    });
});
```

You can even add your own right-click menu instead of the browser's context menu and add the same link here:

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/erdemolcay/syshu1v7/)

```
$('img').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("<div class='custom-right-click-menu'><a id='download-btn' href='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' download='image.png'>Save image</a></div>")
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px"
        });
});

$(document).bind("click", function (event) {
    $(".custom-right-click-menu").hide();
});

$(function () {
    $('#download-btn').click(function () {
        // Do whatever you want...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use my own right-click menu